# What is a .ddf file and what does it have to do with SharePoint Solution creation?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What is a ddf file and what does it have to do with SharePoint Solution creation?

Answer (score 2):

"A .ddf file is a data directive file and is used when building the Sharepoint solution bundle specifying the source files and their destination locations. The important thing for someone to understand is that the .ddf file will be passed as a parameter to the MAKECAB utility to orchestrate construction of the Sharepoint solution file."

http://www.dotnetspark.com/qa/1932-what-is-ddf-file-and-what-does-it-have-to.aspx

Some discussion [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31574/making-a-cab-file-with-ddf-to-create-a-wsp-solution-package) also.